# How do I prevent the current kernel from being replaced in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, kernel, update-manager, synaptic

So how do I do it?
I Can't find sypaptic, in where I remember that I could "lock" certain packages to ensure that they kept their current version.

Comment: Synaptic Package Manager is not installed by default any more but you can install it through Ubuntu Software Centre and it still lets you lock a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aptitude.  `sudo aptitude hold linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic`

this updates the sources and does an upgrade like synaptic/apt-get dist-upgrade would  `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade` and with the first command your kernel will be held and ignored

Comment: This seems to work when updating from the terminal. The graphical Update manager however seems to ignore holdback packages. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, only aptitude will know you held it back.. bummer I know.